# Sitecore9 reading date time issue

Tags: datetimepicker

I'm working on local instance where i saved date 08/01/2019 7:00 PM to sitecore item when i read this item from database I can read correct date but when i read from Solr index I was able to read 08/02/2019 1:00 AM,

There is 6 hour difference when i change the time, difference stays the same 6 hours, it is **important** that my time zone difference is exactly 6 hours from GMT, as sitecore instance is running on my local machine where time zone is set to (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US and Canada)

When i google it i came to know this setting in sitecore.config file

```
<setting name="ServerTimeZone" value="" />
```

I took help from [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/gg154758(v=winembedded.80)) page and set different time zones but there was no effect on result

I also came across Solr setting in /bin/solr.in.sh file but did not help

```
SOLR_TIMEZONE=UTC
```

Date property/field looks like below, in Sitecore 7.2 it was working good but issue started with Sitecore 9

```
[IndexField("StartDate")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

Note: I was having issue while posting question as there was no available tag like Datetime or Server Time Zone etc.

Comment: Did you try to use this function "DateUtil.ToServerTime(Date)" while you are getting date?

Comment: I updated to my question how datetime field looks, it was working good in Sitecore 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting as below in sitecore.config i was able to get correct date

```
<setting name="ServerTimeZone" value="UTC" />
```

Please note that for previous versions i believe its in sitecore.analystics.config file